# Create new key for a data frame by combining different columns

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` with 4 columns, "id1", "id2", "id3", and "name", where "id1", "id2", and "id3" are very long strings.

I need to connect "id1", "id2", and "id3" together to generate a new key; "id1" + "id2" + "id3" may be duplicated. In other words, each new key is a new combination of the values in "id1" + "id2" + "id3".

I want this new key simple and short such as 'key1', 'key2' etc...

Comment: but you "newbie brain" can dot it inefficiently and show what he have tried? Some input data also and the expected result...

Comment: For thoses how downvotes without any explanation, I don't think your are of a great help for the OP. Actually, it is a good question but not well formulated.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
set.seed(42)
DF <- data.frame(key1=sample(letters[1:2],10,TRUE),
                 key2=sample(letters[1:2],10,TRUE),
                 key3=sample(letters[1:2],10,TRUE))

DF <- within(DF,{newkey <- interaction(key1,key2,key3,drop=TRUE)
                 levels(newkey) <- paste0("key",seq_along(levels(newkey)))
                 })

#    key1 key2 key3 newkey
# 1     b    a    b   key4
# 2     b    b    a   key2
# 3     a    b    b   key5
# 4     b    a    b   key4
# 5     b    a    a   key1
# 6     b    b    b   key6
# 7     b    b    a   key2
# 8     a    a    b   key3
# 9     b    a    a   key1
# 10    b    b    b   key6
```

Comment: +1! maybe I would create longer key1,key2,.. string in my sample.

Comment: when data size is small, it work great. But when I tried data frame with 500k rows, it got overflow error, as R try to allocate a vector of length of 1340 million

Comment: How many unique key values are there for each id? Please give a reproducible example of how your data actually looks like. You can find out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1412059) how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `.GRP` from "data.table" fro this. It also shouldn't struggle with 500k rows of data:

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(DF)[, combined := .GRP, by = names(DF)][]
#     key1 key2 key3 combined
#  1:    b    a    b        1
#  2:    b    b    a        2
#  3:    a    b    b        3
#  4:    b    a    b        1
#  5:    b    a    a        4
#  6:    b    b    b        5
#  7:    b    b    a        2
#  8:    a    a    b        6
#  9:    b    a    a        4
# 10:    b    b    b        5
```

If you need the combined key to be sorted according to a sorted set of the other keys, use `setkey` before doing the above step.